# WCF: Is there a way to return different datetime serialization based on the http Accept-Language header?

Tags: c#, wcf, internationalization, wcf-rest

I would like my REST service to return a DateTime as:

- 01-**dec**-2009 for Accept-Language: en-US
- 01-**dez**-2009 for Accept-Language: pt-BR

Thanks!

André Carlucci

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that "serialization" means "converting something to text format for interchange/storage" and not to present to a human reader.

By this definition, it must be language independent, and follow the XML serialization convention, or ISO 8601, or a CultureInfo::InvariantCulture. See also http://www.mihai-nita.net/article.php?artID=20051025a

If we don't call it "serialization" then

Answer (score 0):

How are you serializing those DateTimes?

It looks to me like they've been converted to strings, in which case you should be able to inspect the [Request.UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx) property and inject the appropriate CultureInfo into an ordinary string.Format() call.

The standard XML serializer uses a culture-agnostic format explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp):

*The dateTime is specified in the following form "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss" where:*

- YYYY indicates the year
- MM indicates the month
- DD indicates the day
- T indicates the start of the required time section
- hh indicates the hour
- mm indicates the minute
- ss indicates the second

Note that these should be in UTC.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, that's the way, but how to get access to the Accept-Language header in my WebGet method?

Comment: So the answer is: "there is no way"?

Comment: @andrecarlucci: try looking at `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers` to see the headers for the incoming request.